# Update BackContent after midnight

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, tile

I have an application which counts my expenses, and I set a limit in it,and add also records with expenses.. On the Secondary Tile  in BackContent I show how much money there left me.
In my application I also set a limit for a day.

I need to launch update a BackContent after midnight to show how much there left me for a current day.

Is it possilble, to have something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be done with a Background Agent, i have never done this so i only can suggest you some links.

[Live Tile Changes (BlogSpot)](http://dotnet-redzone.blogspot.com/2011/06/windows-phone-live-tile-changes-with.html)

[BackgroundAgent MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)